# Tree with unlimited branches

Tags: c#, tree

So I want to make a tree in c# that has 3 classes: Tree class(contains register and print methods)>>Branches(it needs to be recursive)>>District class(contains Name and Area). Basically, I'm trying to make the program where a user could input Cities and districts into a list and then do things with it like search items, etc. So the question is how do I make these classes connected, and make this work? I was searching similar topics but couldn't find this, sorry if this was already asked. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    public class Node
    {
        public List<Node> children = new List<Node>();
        public District district { get; set; }

        public void Print()
        {
        }
        public void Register()
        {
        }

    }
    public class District
    {
        string name { get; set;}
        string area { get; set; }
    }
```